# single result for 2 queries ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a POST table, a CATEGORY table, a ACTION table and ACTION_TYPE table, I explain the ACTION table contains all the actions that were made, and the table ACTION_TYPE contains the actions details for example the ACTION whose ID = 4 has ACTION_TYPE_ID = 1 for POST_ID 6, which mean an action was made for post number 50, we can have many actions for one post_id

The POST table

```
 id         title       content     category_id
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------  
 1          title1      Text...     1
 2          title2      Text...     1
 3          title3      Text...     1
 4          title4      Text...     3
 5          title5      Text...     2
 6          title6      Text...     1
```

The CATEGORY table

```
 id         name      
----------  ----------  
 1          category_1      
 2          category_2
 3          category_3
```

The ACTION_TYPE table

```
 id         name      
----------  ----------  
 1          updated
 2          deleted
 3          restored
 4          hided
```

The ACTION table

```
id         post_id         action_type_id    date
----------  ----------      --------------    -----
 1          1               1                 2017-01-01
 2          1               1                 2017-02-15
 3          1               3                 2018-06-10
 4          6               1                 2019-08-01
 5          5               2                 2019-12-09
 6          2               3                 2020-04-27
 7          2               1                 2020-07-29
 8          3               2                 2021-03-13
```

Now I explain the case, I actually have two queries a query to count the posts for each category and another to count the actions performed on each post by category which work perfectly.

Here is my first query

```
select categories,  count(*) as cnt_posts_per_cat
   from(
        select 
        case
        when p.category_id is not null then c.name
        end as categories
        from post p  
        left join category c on p.category _id = c.id
        )
   group by categories
;
```

Which brings this result

```
categories  cnt_posts_per_cat
----------  -------------------   
category_1  4
category_2  1
category_3  1
```

Ans here is my second query

```
select categories,  count(*) as cnt_actions_per_cat
   from(
        select  distinct  ac.post_id  AS action_post_id, max(ac.date) over (partition by  ac.post_id) as max_date, 
        case
        when ac.action_type_id is not null then act.name
        end as actions,
        case
        when p.category_id is not null then c.name
        else 'na'
        end as categories
        from action ac
        left join post p on ac.post_id = p.id  
        left join category c on p.category _id = c.id
        left join action_type act on ac.action_type_id = act.id
        where act.name in ('restored','deleted','updated')
        )
   group by categories
;
```

Which brings this correct result because it's seclect the last action for each action_type

```
categories  cnt_actions_per_cat
----------  -------------------   
category_1  3
category_2  1
category_3  na
```

But I would like to have a single result table for both queries at the same time as follow :
Here the result expected to be

```
categories  cnt_posts_per_cat   cnt_actions_per_cat
----------  -----------------   -------------------  
category_1  4                   3
category_2  1                   1
category_3  1                   na
```

i was trying union and union all but it's not correct it return following result

```
categories  cnt_posts_per_cat   
----------  -----------------   
category_1  7                  
category_2  2                  
category_3  1
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

How about correlated subqueries?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  post (id, category_id) as
  3    (select 1, 1 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 3 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 2 from dual union all
  8     select 6, 1 from dual
  9    ),
 10  category (id, name) as
 11    (select 1, 'category_1' from dual union all
 12     select 2, 'category_2' from dual union all
 13     select 3, 'category_3' from dual
 14    ),
 15  action_type (id, name) as
 16    (select 1, 'updated' from dual union all
 17     select 2, 'deleted' from dual union all
 18     select 3, 'restored' from dual union all
 19     select 4, 'hided' from dual
 20    ),
 21  action (id, post_id, action_type_id) as
 22    (select 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
 23     select 2, 1, 1 from dual union all
 24     select 3, 1, 3 from dual union all
 25     select 4, 6, 1 from dual union all
 26     select 5, 5, 2 from dual union all
 27     select 6, 2, 3 from dual union all
 28     select 7, 2, 1 from dual union all
 29     select 8, 3, 2 from dual
 30    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 31  select c.name,
 32    --
 33    (select count(*)
 34     from post p
 35     where p.category_id = c.id
 36    ) cnt_posts_per_cat,
 37    --
 38    (select count(*)
 39     from action a join post p        on p.id = a.post_id
 40                   join action_type t on t.id = a.id
 41     where p.category_id = c.id
 42       and t.name in ('restored', 'deleted', 'updated')
 43    ) cnt_actions_per_cat
 44  from category c
 45  order by c.name;

NAME       CNT_POSTS_PER_CAT CNT_ACTIONS_PER_CAT
---------- ----------------- -------------------
category_1                 4                   3
category_2                 1                   0
category_3                 1                   0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying i appreciate it but what about this line i need this one to select the last action for each action_type "select  distinct  ac.post_id  AS action_post_id, max(ac.date) over (partition by  ac.post_id) as max_date, "  when i add it i get following error : 
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"